# How to get a zombie pigman from the nether into the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to get a certain Zombie Pigman through a portal into the overworld. However my attempts have been unsuccessful. I've tried:

- Pushing it into the portal
- Having it independently wander into the portal
- Boating it into the portal
- Carting it to the portal

All to no avail. The pigman just idles in the portal.
Some notes:

- Other Zombie Pigmen are easily teleported when entering the portal
- I am aware there is a 300 tick cooldown on the portal and i've been waiting the 15 seconds before attempting to bring it into the portal again
- The pigman was spawned in hard mode with an enchanted sword and the Pigman is named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-151648

I do not know what causes it and how you can work around it. The best you can do is to name another pigman, vote for the report and comment if you encountered it in a version that is not already listed.

Comment: @Robotnik The affected versions in that ticket are just what people tested it in so far. It was not marked as fixed yet and I even specifically asked to comment on it if the bug was seen in 1.15.2 or later. I'm also not planning to update this answer every single time someone adds a version to that report. I have 616 gamingSE answers, 25 of those linking Mojira and I watch 990 reports on Mojira. I will for sure not keep up with all the versions added to reports I linked. Also, I like that arrow, but not in this situation. Ranges are `-` or `..`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! you can take a swipe at one, then run **THROUGH** the nether portal. Then the zombie pigmen will instantly go through. Notice: They are waiting in the overworld. So be careful.

How to take them back without making them angry? 
Not so easy, a lightning strike have to hit a pig, which is rare but possible. Then you have a zombie pigman!
 Other ways?

Zombie Pigmen have a very slight chance of spawning near a nether portal or they can walk through the Portal themselves if the group around is spawnable and the portal is within wander distance. (Very rare)

Comment: I think "chance of spawning near" a portal is actually them spawning on the loaded side of the nether and wandering in, I've added this to the post as another way to get them in the overworld.

Welcome to Arqade by the way!

Comment: On the Xbox One, I somehow managed to get a non-hostile pigman to follow me back to the overworld, without actually trying to do so. I just went in my basement one day and discovered the little guy wandering around in there.

Comment: The question states that the pigman is already inside the portal. It just does not get teleported to the Overworld.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Minecraft. So I'm very sorry for any mistakes.